# Why is std::bitset::at() throwing out_of_range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, exception, stl

This has stumped me for a few hours now, since I cannot see any problem in the math or code.  (Dispite staring at it and working it out over and over again to be sure.)  I'm hoping you folks can help me, here's my code:

```
#define SOLVE_POSITION(x, y, z) ( z*16  +  y*4  +  x )

std::bitset<64> block;
block.reset();

for(int z = 0; z < 4; ++z){
    for(int y = 0; y < 4; ++y){
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; ++x){

            if(block.at(SOLVE_POSITION(3-x, y, 3-z))){  //<-- call to at() throws 'out_of_range'

                // do stuff
            };
        };
    };
};
```

With `z` being 0, the two inner most for loops run their course entirely (for a total of 16 passes.)  However, once `z` becomes 1, that's when the exception is thrown from within std::bitset<64>::at().

The values of `z`, `y`, `x` are respectively  `1`, `0`, `0` at that moment.

Can you tell me what is happening here to cause this exception?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros! You have to be really careful about this:

You define:

```
#define SOLVE_POSITION(x, y, z) ( z*16  +  y*4  +  x )
```

so when you do:

```
SOLVE_POSITION(3-x, y, 3-z)
```

it expands to:

```
( 3-x*16 + y*4 + 3-z )
```

and because of operator precedence, `3-x*16` will be incorrect! You need to do:

```
#define SOLVE_POSITION(x, y, z) ( (z)*16  +  (y)*4  +  (x) )
```

so that it expands correctly to:

```
( (3-x)*16 + (y)*4 + (3-z) )
```

as expected.

Comment: ... Wow, I feel like I walked straight into a trap with that!  Thank you, it finally works now!

Comment: @Clairvoire: Begs the question why you would even use a macro here given all the chances for messing it up.

Comment: Well, with the parenthesis, it works fine.  If I avoided everything that had a chance of messing up, I wouldn't be a C++ programmer.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Macros use text substitution, you're effectively telling the compiler

```
SOLVE_POSITION(3-x, y, 3-z) => SOLVE_POSITION( 3-z*16  +  y*4  +  3-x )
```

To fix this, make sure you surround your macro arguments with parenthesis:

```
#define SOLVE_POSITION(x, y, z) ( (z)*16  +  (y)*4  +  (x) )
```

Comment: This is why inline functions are often recommended as a replacement for function-like macros.